# What happened to the Dragons?

Tags: fairy-tail

Dragons are assumed to be myth or somewhat a legend in someway in Fairy Tail. They also disappeared in Fairy Tail. But what was the reason behind them disappearing. We have seen in an episode that Grandeeney and Igneel are still very much alive, but seem to look as though they are in hiding. Also what's up with all dragons disappearing on the same day and the same year?

Answers are appreciated :). If there's anything from the manga, please include in answer. I do not think they have covered it in the anime.

Comment: There's no need to include a spoiler warning in you post. if you have spoilers, please use the `>!` spoiler markdown to enclose you content. E.g., `>! spoiler here!`

Comment: Additionally, if you mention an episode, please try to indicate which episode so people can get on the same page and don't have to guess which episode you're referring to.

Comment: i think they are hiding because something happened on the day before they left there foster children so they wont have to get caught in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, little has been revealed.

> On July 7, X777, all the Dragons, except Acnologia, seemingly vanished, most notably, Igneel, Metalicana, and Grandeeney, who each abandoned their young foster children, leaving the species to be remembered as little more than a myth.
>
> To the events of the year X784, society does not believe in the existence of Dragons. However, the destruction of Tenrou Island caused by one of them, called Acnologia, changed society's view on this issue.

http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Dragons

Answer (score 2):

There were several reasons why the Dragons disappeared at that time and it was revealed in chapter 415.

In the end, the dragons were indeed still *alive*. They hid themselves inside the dragon slayers' bodies. The reasons behind this were threefold:

- The dragons were afraid a new human would become so powerful that he would transform into a dragon, just like Acnologia. To prevent this from happening they went inside their bodies to slow down their power increase.
- The second reason was that the dragons were waiting for the right time to defeat Acnologia. Despite this reason clearly being stated by Grandeeney, I have a hard time believing it. Especially since the dragons did not fight Acnologia at all. They just watched Igneel get defeated. If they had attacked together, they might have been able to do more damage I believe.
- The third and probably main reason why the dragons all disappeared was that Acnologia used his magic to extract their souls from their bodies. In order to prolong their lives, they retreated their souls (and apparently their bodies too) inside the dragon slayers they had once raised.

[image: enter image description here!]
[image: enter image description here!]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, all the dragons left there foster children (Gajeel, Wendy Natsu) because they didnt want them to turn into dragons. it explains later in the show that if a dragon slayer becomes powerful enough, he/she can actually turn into a dragon. They didn't want this to happen, so they went into hiding.